# ADICUP360 and CrossCore Embedded Studio - error: No source available for "_start() at 0x150"

Tags: ide, embedded, microcontroller, disassembly, cortex-m

The demo projects of the ADuCM360 / ADICUP360 from https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/eval-adicup360 are working fine.
But if I try to create (*build project* -> *debug as*) my own project, for example just something like this:

```
#include <sys/platform.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* Begin adding your custom code here */

    return 0;
}
```

Then I receive the error message:

> No source available for "_start() at 0x150"

When I then press the button *View Disassembly*, then i get the following result:

```
00000150:   bkpt    0x00ab
00000152:   ldr     r0, [pc, #192]  ; (0x214 <_start+200>)
00000154:   ldr     r1, [r0, #4]
00000156:   cmp     r1, #0
00000158:   beq.n   0x15e <_start+18>
0000015a:   ldr     r2, [pc, #212]  ; (0x230 <_start+228>)
0000015c:   str     r1, [r2, #0]
0000015e:   ldr     r1, [r0, #0]
00000160:   cmp     r1, #0
00000162:   bne.n   0x168 <_start+28>
00000164:   ldr     r1, [pc, #196]  ; (0x22c <_start+224>)
00000166:   str     r1, [r0, #0]
00000168:   ldr     r1, [r0, #8]
0000016a:   ldr     r2, [r0, #12]
0000016c:   cmp     r1, #0
0000016e:   beq.n   0x172 <_start+38>
00000170:   mov     sp, r1
00000172:   cmp     r2, #0
00000174:   beq.n   0x17a <_start+46>
00000176:   add.w   r10, r2, #256   ; 0x100
0000017a:   movs    r1, #0
0000017c:   mov     r11, r1
0000017e:   mov     r7, r1
00000180:   ldr     r0, [pc, #148]  ; (0x218 <_start+204>)
00000182:   ldr     r2, [pc, #152]  ; (0x21c <_start+208>)
00000184:   subs    r2, r2, r0
00000186:   bl      0x41c <memset>
0000018a:   bl      0x6c0 <initialise_monitor_handles>
0000018e:   movs    r0, #21
00000190:   ldr     r1, [pc, #148]  ; (0x228 <_start+220>)
00000192:   bkpt    0x00ab
00000194:   ldr     r1, [pc, #144]  ; (0x228 <_start+220>)
00000196:   ldr     r1, [r1, #0]
00000198:   movs    r0, #0
0000019a:   push    {r0}
0000019c:   ldrb    r3, [r1, #0]
0000019e:   adds    r1, #1
000001a0:   cmp     r3, #0
000001a2:   beq.n   0x1d0 <_start+132>
000001a4:   cmp     r3, #32
000001a6:   beq.n   0x19c <_start+80>
000001a8:   cmp     r3, #34 ; 0x22
000001aa:   beq.n   0x1b0 <_start+100>
000001ac:   cmp     r3, #39 ; 0x27
000001ae:   bne.n   0x1b4 <_start+104>
000001b0:   movs    r2, r3
000001b2:   b.n     0x1b8 <_start+108>
000001b4:   movs    r2, #32
000001b6:   subs    r1, #1
000001b8:   push    {r1}
000001ba:   adds    r0, #1
000001bc:   ldrb    r3, [r1, #0]
000001be:   adds    r1, #1
000001c0:   cmp     r3, #0
000001c2:   beq.n   0x1d0 <_start+132>
......... ...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That is the C runtime start-up - possibly provided to you project as object code, hence no source.

Do you need source-level debugging of the start-up code? If so you need to include the source (which is quite possibly in assembly code in any case if it is available to you at all).

Place a break point in or on `main()` and continue until you are in code for which you *can* provide the source.

The question is why you have a breakpoint instruction (soft breakpoint) at `_start()`? Did you set that, or did your debugger automatically insert it?

The CrossCore compiler manual refers to the "System Run-Time Documentation" for details of the runtime start-up, but one of the FAQ's is ["Where is the System Run-Time Documentation?"](https://ez.analog.com/dsp/software-and-development-tools/cces/w/documents/13838/faq-where-is-system-run-time-documentation).

Comment: Hi, first of all: thx for you answer. I don't need to source-level debugging of the start code. And I didn't place any breakpoint instruction at start. I think the debugger inserted it automatically. But I don't know why. The settings of the demo projects which are working and the settings of my project seem to be the same. I will try to place a break point in main() and hope that it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

The better and easy way to start is take working example ( for example blink project),remove contents of main function and add your custom code there.

I understand from your comment that you are debugging the code.
May I know
1. How the behavior is if step over from breakpoint is done?
2. What is the behavior in free run?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, just editing the already existing example projects.